# Why is it true that any polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in a finite field $F_q$ is separable over that field?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Why is it true that any polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in a finite field $F_q$ is separable over that field?

I'm confused because the polynomial $x^2+1$ in $F_2[x]$ is inseparable ($f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are not coprime), and yet apparently this property is true.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Any *irreducible* polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb F_q$ is separable. If you drop the irreducibility condition, it's never true, over any field, because you can always consider $f(x) = x^2$, which has $0$ as a repeated root.

Comment: I think I misunderstood my professor's definition of separability.  I understand now that f(x) is separable if all of its irreducible factors are separable.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a field $E$ being perfect is that every **irreducible** polynomial $p\in E[x]$ is separable ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field)). But the polynomial $x^2+1$ is equal to $(x+1)^2$ in $\mathbf{F}_2[x]$, so it's not irreducible.

Similarly, the field $\mathbf{Q}$ being perfect doesn't conflict with $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2\in\mathbf{Q}[x]$ having repeated roots.